# How to make popover close in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to close popover by clicking outside (or click on screen). What I do wrong in this case?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Popover Example</a>
   <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Hide</button>
   </div>   
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[data-toggle='popover']").click(function(){
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('show');
});
$(body).click(function(){
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide');
});

});
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/1rbddcap/1/

Answer (score 0):

You had two issues in your code:

1) `$(body)` should be `$('body')`. tagname selector need to be wrapped in quote.

2) stop parent body event propogation to popover click for making show function work.

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation()
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('show');
});
$('body').click(function(){
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide');
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ctorajnu/)**

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code may help you to solve the issue

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").click(function(){
        $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('show');
        return false;
    });
    $('body').click(function(){
        $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide');
    });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Popover Example</a>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Hide</button>
  </div>   
</div>
```